# accessing a javascript/css from within zend framework's application directory

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, view, url-routing

so suppose inside the views/scripts directories within the application folder of my zend framework project, I would like to put in javascript/css files and then I would like to add these to my pages...

what would be the best way in doing so since if I just put in the full path to the file it will complain that it can't find the 'application' controller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript and CSS (and images, flash and any other public, static asset) should go under the `public` directory.

You reference these in your view / layout using the appropriate view helper

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile(
        $this->baseUrl('path/to/script.js')) ?>
```

If you *must* place these in your `application` directory, consider creating symbolic links under the public directory.